# ComboBox value that isn't in the list shows as blank in Java 11

Tags: java, javafx

I'm migrating a project from Java 8 to Java 11. It seems that the behaviour of ComboBox has changed when showing a value that is not in the list.

- In Java 8 "CHERRY" would be shown when the button is pressed.
- In Java 11 it's just blank, also Java 14, on both Windows and RedHat 8.2.

I've been debugging the underlying Skin code, I've found some reference which suggests it should work
in `javafx.scene.control.skin.ComboBoxListViewSkin.updateDisplayNode()`

```
// RT-21336 Show the ComboBox value even though it doesn't
// exist in the ComboBox items list (part two of fix)
```

Is there any known workaround for this?

SSCCE

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ComboBoxIssue extends Application {

    public enum Fruit {
        APPLE, BANANA, CHERRY
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        ComboBox<Fruit> fruits = new ComboBox<>();
        fruits.getItems().addAll(Fruit.APPLE, Fruit.BANANA);
        fruits.setValue(Fruit.APPLE);
        Button button = new Button("Change");
        button.setOnAction(event -> {
            fruits.setValue(Fruit.CHERRY);
        });
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new VBox(fruits, button)));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

}
```

Comment: I don’t mean to be flippant, but wouldn’t the most reliable solution be to forbid setting the value to something which isn’t in the item list?  Is there a valid use case for doing otherwise?

Comment: @VGR given that JavaFX 8 supported this then I'd say yes :)

Comment: @VGR no, having an uncontained item as selectedItem is specified quite at the top of the SelectionModel hierarchy and combo.value specified to be the same as the model's selectedItem :) The most reliable solution is to clean up the mess in combo's skin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue has already been reported as [JDK-8221722](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8221722)  and has not yet been fixed. A workaround exists on the duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55386928/898289

The root cause is that code in `javafx.scene.control.skin.ComboBoxListViewSkin.updateDisplayText(ListCell<T>, T, boolean)` directly modifies the text of the control

```
String s = item == null && promptText != null ? promptText :
                   c == null ? (item == null ? null : item.toString()) : c.toString(item);
cell.setText(s);
```

However the item of the cell (javafx.scene.control.Cell.item) is still null.

New code added between Java 8 and 11 in `javafx.scene.control.Cell` does an additional layout pass after the cell has been updated which causes it to blank by re-writing the null item which then clears the text.

```
/** {@inheritDoc} */
@Override protected void layoutChildren() {
    if (itemDirty) {
        updateItem(getItem(), isEmpty());
        itemDirty = false;
    }
    super.layoutChildren();
}
```

Comment: _there are several interwoven issues around combo selection and sync'ing its selection state across listView and displayNode_ citing from https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8087523 (note to self: add references ;)